# How to reorder the data from array?

Tags: php, arrays

just want to ask if how i gonna reorder the data from the array using site name? I want to display only one data at a time when the site name is loop.

for example the site order is this

```
site1
site2
site3
site4
```

What I want is this and it it must be order by highest rate or number:

```
name: John Doe
site: site1
rate: 10



name: Joen Doe
site: site2
rate: 10

name: Ejon Odeo
site: Site3
rate: 9.7

name: Ejosan Odeo
site: Site4
rate: 9.5

name: John Smith
site: site1
rate: 9.3

name: Jodsen Dsoe
site: site2
rate: 8

name: Efsdjon Oddeo
site: Site3
rate: 6.3
```

and so on...

It will loop until it will all print.

**Name Array:**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 10 [site] => site here)
Array ( [1] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 9 [site] => site here)
Array ( [2] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 8 [site] => site here)
Array ( [3] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 7 [site] => site here)
Array ( [4] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 6 [site] => site here)
Array ( [5] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 5 [site] => site here)
Array ( [6] => Array ( [name] => name here [rate] => 5 [site] => site here)
```

**Site Array**
I want to display only one person in every site name from array and when the site array is reached into the end then it will start again in **exs** site name until the persons array is all displayed.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [acronym] => exs [site_order] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [acronym] => ts [site_order] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [acronym] => ih [site_order] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [acronym] => tp [site_order] => 3 ) [4] => Array ( [acronym] => tc [site_order] => 4 ) [5] => Array ( [acronym] => cfnm [site_order] => 5 ) [6] => Array ( [acronym] => sn [site_order] => 6 ) [7] => Array ( [acronym] => tla [site_order] => 7 ) [8] => Array ( [acronym] => bsc [site_order] => 8 ) [9] => Array ( [acronym] => tdp [site_order] => 9 ) [10] => Array ( [acronym] => lhd [site_order] => 10 ) [11] => Array ( [acronym] => ss [site_order] => 11 ) [12] => Array ( [acronym] => pov [site_order] => 12 ) [13] => Array ( [acronym] => rat [site_order] => 13 ) [14] => Array ( [acronym] => trw [site_order] => 14 ) [15] => Array ( [acronym] => tgs [site_order] => 15 ) [16] => Array ( [acronym] => tlm [site_order] => 16 ) [17] => Array ( [acronym] => ol [site_order] => 17 ) [18] => Array ( [acronym] => tb [site_order] => 18 ) [19] => Array ( [acronym] => ta [site_order] => 19 ) [20] => Array ( [acronym] => hfy [site_order] => 20 ) [21] => Array ( [acronym] => sd [site_order] => 21 ) [22] => Array ( [acronym] => si [site_order] => 22 ) [23] => Array ( [acronym] => tse [site_order] => 23 ) )
```

the acronym in site array is the site name. pls help me guys

Answer (score 1):

have a look at `usort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
<?php

// your example array
$data = array(
    0 => array('name' => 'name 1', 'rate' => 1, 'site' => 'site 8'),
    1 => array('name' => 'name 2', 'rate' => 2, 'site' => 'site 9'),
    2 => array('name' => 'name 3', 'rate' => 4, 'site' => 'site 10'),
    3 => array('name' => 'name 4', 'rate' => 3, 'site' => 'site 11'),
    4 => array('name' => 'name 5', 'rate' => 6, 'site' => 'site 12'),
    5 => array('name' => 'name 6', 'rate' => 7, 'site' => 'site 13'),
    6 => array('name' => 'name 7', 'rate' => 5, 'site' => 'site 14')
);

// sort array with user defined function, see below
usort($data, 'sortByRate');

// now you can walk through the array and print it
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo 'name: '.$item['name'].'<br>';
    echo 'site: '.$item['site'].'<br>';
    echo 'rate: '.$item['rate'].'<br>';
    echo '<br>';
}


// function wich sorts the array
function sortByRate($a, $b) {
    if ($a['rate'] == $b['rate']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['rate'] > $b['rate']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Comment: what if the order of the site name is

9,8,14,13,11,12,10 ?

Comment: im just wondering if how i gonna display by this site name order? for example the site name array is this? and it must be ordered according to site name and the rate must be in order too?

Comment: do you have any idea mate?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to sort a multidimensional array by one value. [This question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value). For your specific circumstances, you could alter your code like this (with PHP 5.3 and higher, that is):

```
usort($someArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['rate'] - $b['rate'];
});
```